# CATextlayer font size not changing when export video from AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, calayer

I am adding text on video by using CATextLayer. but when export process done text size is not changing by frame position. font size print in log but not change in CATextLayer fontsize. here is my code which i have done.

```
let mainCompositionInst = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    var naturalSize = CGSize()
    naturalSize = CGSize(width: (videoAssetTrack?.naturalSize.width)!, height:(videoAssetTrack?.naturalSize.height)!)
    var renderWidth = CGFloat()
    var renderHeight = CGFloat()

    renderWidth = naturalSize.width
    renderHeight = naturalSize.height

    mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSize(width: renderWidth, height: renderHeight)
    mainCompositionInst.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

let myAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 30)!, // font
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white                   // text color
    ]
    let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Title", attributes: myAttributes )

    let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
    titleLayer.string = myAttributedString

    titleLayer.frame = CGRect(x: (dragView?.frame.origin.x)!, y: (dragView?.frame.origin.y)!, width: (dragView?.frame.size.width)!, height: (dragView?.frame.height)!)
    titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    titleLayer.isWrapped = true


    print("Font Size \(String(describing: titleLayer.fontSize))")
    let overlayLayer = CALayer()
    overlayLayer.addSublayer(titleLayer)
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: naturalSize.width, height: naturalSize.height)
    overlayLayer.masksToBounds = true

    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: naturalSize.width, height: naturalSize.height)
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: naturalSize.width, height: naturalSize.height)


    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)

    mainCompositionInst.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool.init(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just one line added and code works fine `titleLayer.shouldRasterize = true`

Comment: Were you able to get the isWrapped working with the export?